# Can I use iPhone 5 (version 10.3.4) for flutter iOS debugging?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I am trying to debug my flutter iOS project with a real iPhone device which is iPhone 5. My Xcode application is not showing my iPhone 5 in the device list. Can I run my flutter iOS project in my iPhone 5?

```
Xcode version: 12.3
iPhone 5 version: 10.3.4
```

Comment: Yes, You can but before that, you need to set your minimum iOS version as 10.0 or 10.2. But I prefer to run your app on the latest simulator or device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Of course you can run your flutter project in a real IOS device. Check your connection between your iPhone and system which is used by you. If this solution doesn't work then restart your Xcode otherwise restart your system after connect your iPhone with your system a pop-up menu appears in iPhone to ask "Trust this computer" click on trust. And You need to set the deployment target according to your iPhone version. Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

This snippet came out at the transition from 32-bit to 64-bit hardware for iPhones:

> The following iOS devices are 64-bit:
>
> - iPhone 5s/SE/6/6s/7
> - iPad Air and iPad Air 2
> - iPad mini 2, iPad mini 3 and iPad mini 4
> - Sixth-generation iPod touch
> - 12.9-inch iPad Pro and 9.7-inch iPad Pro
> - 9.7-inch iPad (2017)

https://medium.com/@ClrMobile/why-is-apple-dropping-32-bit-app-support-and-how-will-it-impact-your-app-d2a0b0ab56e0

I recall Flutter needing 64-bit ARM, which would seem to preclude an iPhone 5 according to the above list.